# How do I create an empty model to pass to an insert-update view when there are more than on model in the dbcontext?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, dbcontext, insert-update

I need to create an empty form for database update. In the controller this is called: `public ViewResult Create() => View("Edit", new List());`

```
<TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
I have a class MeetingListContext : DbContext that has 3 models:
1. DbSet List
2. DbSet ATime (Look up table to show time name instead of time id)
3. DbSet DOW (Look up table to show day name instead of day id)
```

Model

```
namespace DEIGList.Models
{
    public partial class MeetingListContext : DbContext
    {
        public MeetingListContext()
        {
        }

        public MeetingListContext(DbContextOptions<MeetingListContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        public virtual DbSet<ATime> ATime { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Dow> Dow { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<List> List { get; set; }
```

The View:

```
@model DEIGList.Models.MeetingListContext
```

In the controller:

```
 public ViewResult Create() => View("Edit", new List());
```

The expected result will be a form with empty data fields for fill in data.
I would like to be able to use drop downs (lookups) for the day and time.

But when I use `@model DEIGList.Models.MeetingListContext` I get:

```
InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'DEIGList.Models.List', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type 'DEIGList.Models.MeetingListContext'.
```

Suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You need change from `@model DEIGList.Models.MeetingListContext`

to `@model DEIGList.Models.List`

The type of @model must same type with type of model in `View("Edit", new List())`

Update:

If you want to have drop down for Day and Time, you need update Controller:

```
public ViewResult Create() {
    MeetingListContext ctx = new MeetingListContext();
    ViewBag.ATime = ctx.ATime.ToList();
    ViewBag.Dow  = ctx.Dow.ToList();
    return View("Edit", new List());
}
```

Add dropdown helper in View:

```
@Html.DropDownList("ATime", new SelectList(ViewBag.ATime, "ATimeID", "ATimeName"))
@Html.DropDownList("Dow", new SelectList(ViewBag.Dow, "DowID", "DowName"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your post pointed me towards a solution. The solution was to do a select with an id == 0.

```html
var list = _context.List
     .Where(l => l.ListId == 0)
     .Include(t => t.ATime)
     .Include(d => d.Dow)
     .ToList();
 ViewBag.thelist = list;

 return View("Edit", new List());
```